How to filter out certain characters in a range of cells
I want to remove the months from a range of cells like below:
11.2008-12.2011
03.2007-12.2011
09.2007-12.2011
09.2006-12.2011

End result should be like this:
2008-2011
2007-2011
2007-2011
2006-2011

How do I do that?

On LibreOffice Calc, you can directly use Find and Replace and select Regular expressions option.

Press Ctrl+H
Find: \d+\.(\d+-)\d+\.(\d+)
Replace: $1$2
Check Regular expressions box
Click Replace All

This should allow you to remove and replace the months on the same cells.

Demo


I actually did it with following formulas:
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)-4,5) "End result is 2008- for first row"

=MID(B2,FIND("-",B2)+4,4) "End result is 2011 for first row"

Then I merge two cells:
=TEXTJOIN( , ,D2,E2)


I don't have Libreoffice calc to test, but a formula like this should work:
Regex(A1, ".+([0-9]{4}).+([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2")
https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_regex.html
